# php yii - how to get image width and height attributes from yii image component

Tags: php, image, yii, components

im managing my image uploaded by this component

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/

https://github.com/yiiext/image-component

with this component i can resize , rotate , move images & ...

but in this case i want to get size attributes (width and height) of a file

and check it if it's width is bigger than my limit (for example 100px) so resize it to this size and save it...

can i do it with this image component?

i've found the way of checking $image->width or $image->height

is there any other optimized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [Imagine Library](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) so you should be able to access the width and height with

```
$image->getSize()->getWidth();
$image->getSize()->getHeight();
```

And yes of course you can do all kinds of image manipulation with it. We are using it about a year now and are very happy with it.